# SQOOP - Code too large > MAX table definition?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, teradata, sqoop

I'm trying to import data to HDFS from a TERADATA table with 2000 columns (the table definition make 90K caracters)... When I execute my script I get :

```
/tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java:21971: code too large
```

My sqoop script :

```
sqoop import \
 -libjars $LIB_JARS \
 --connect jdbc:teradata://PRD/Database=database \
 --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
 --table table \
 --username login \
 --password pass \
```

My output log :

```
13/11/07 14:54:50 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
13/11/07 14:54:50 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
13/11/07 14:54:50 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
13/11/07 14:55:31 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM table AS t WHERE 1=0
13/11/07 14:55:46 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/..
13/11/07 14:55:46 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core.jar
/tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java:21971: code too large
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
                 ^
/tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java:37949: code too large
  public void write(DataOutput __dataOut) throws IOException {
              ^
/tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java:49925: code too large
  public String toString(DelimiterSet delimiters, boolean useRecordDelim) {
                ^
/tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java:53970: code too large
  private void __loadFromFields(List<String> fields) {
               ^
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoopi/compile/636c527afc3baa6fdf33464f02430602/table.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors
13/11/07 14:55:51 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Error returned by javac
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:205)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:83)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:390)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Maybe someone have already import a big table...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each method in Java is limited to 64KB of byte code. I'm afraid that current version of Sqoop do not have facilities to break the long methods that are being generated in your case into multiple sub-methods, so I would suggest to open a new feature request on [Sqoop JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried this already, but there's Teradata Connector for Hadoop:

http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-now-available

Comment: Yes I try but i think it's not a problem about my connection because when i try on a small table I 'havn't any trouble...